# Counting Functions_discrete

Tags: combinatorics

How many functions are there from the set {1, 2,...,n},
where n is a positive integer, to the set {0, 1}?
a) that assign 0 to both 1 and n?
b) that assign 1 to exactly one of the positive integers less than n?

Part a) i got ..as for n>1,when 0 is assigned to 1 and n , we have (n-2) function values free to be choosen,each having 2 option (0/1) so using product rule it is 2^(n-2)..but for  part b) we have (n-1) function values free to be choosen BUT TO 0...so we have no choice ...so the answer is n-1 according to me ..why answer is 2(n-1)????

Comment: $n$ is not strictly less than $n$, so $f(n)$ could have been either one or zero.  Pick which $k$ it is such that $f(k)=1$ where $k<n$ and let $f(j)=0$ for all other $j<n$ with $j\neq k$ and then after that pick whether $f(n)$ is zero or one.  $n-1$ choices for the first step, and then two choices for the second step.  Applying multiplication principle: $2(n-1)$ functions satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part b, you still have $2$ valid options for $f(n)$, so the answer is $2(n-1)$.

---

You have $n-1$ functions of the form:

- $f_\color\red{1}(i)=
     \cases
     {
      i=\color\red{1}  & 1\\
      i=n              & 0\\
      \text{otherwise} & 0\\
     }
    $
- $f_\color\red{2}(i)=
     \cases
     {
      i=\color\red{2}  & 1\\
      i=n              & 0\\
      \text{otherwise} & 0\\
     }
    $
- $\dots$

---

And another $n-1$ functions of the form:

- $h_\color\red{1}(i)=
     \cases
     {
      i=\color\red{1}  & 1\\
      i=n              & 1\\
      \text{otherwise} & 0\\
     }
    $
- $h_\color\red{2}(i)=
     \cases
     {
      i=\color\red{2}  & 1\\
      i=n              & 1\\
      \text{otherwise} & 0\\
     }
    $
- $\dots$

---

Altogether, you have $2(n-1)$ possible functions.

Comment: what are those..? i mean part b) says  '0' will be assigned to (n-1) elements ...so no option left for (n-1) other than '0'..please let me know which 2 valid option are you telling about?

Comment: @sourav: No options left for $f(1),\dots,f(n-1)$, but still $2$ valid options for $f(n)$. You may have $f(n)=0$ or $f(n)=1$.

Comment: perfect @barak ...thankx..!!

Comment: @sourav: See updated answer, which might help you to understand.

Comment: @sourav: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking ob the V next to it :)